# why my subsite url is showing "..." inside it url when i access the subsite from "Site Settings" >> "look and Feel" >> "Title, Description, and Logo"

Tags: 2013, development, administration, sub-site

I am facing a strange behavioure inside my sub-site. now i have a sub-site of type team site and i can access the sub-site using the following URL:-

```
http://servername/PMO/Programmes/PojectA/
```

now i try to change the sub-site title, by going to "Site Settings" >> "look and Feel" >> "Title, Description, and Logo" .. but i have noted that the sub-site url inside the UI screen is wrong , as it have "`...`" inside it as follow `/PMO/Programmes.../`:-

[image]

which is different from the actual sub-site url,, as i can access the sub-site from `http://servername/PMO/Programmes/PojectA/`?? so i have a feeling as if my sub-site is corrupted ?

now in my case the `/Programmes/` is a parent sub-site and around 2 weeks ago i have changed its url and title from being `Projects` to being `Programmes` so could this caused the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal behavior in SharePoint, by default SharePoint URL label only shows around 50 characters as label, if URL exceed as in your case it replace all remaining characters with dots "..." It's nothing to do with sub-site or "Site Settings>look and Feel" page.

`https://aaaaaaa.sharepoint.com/Project/SubProjectSubProjectSubProject`
SharePoint replace it like this
`https://aaaaaaa.sharepoint.com/Project/SubProjectS.../`
[image]

Comment: thanks for ur reply .. but in my case the scenario is quiet different, as the full URL is being shown (no character truncating) but at the same time additional "..." is being shown !! also i have another subsites which is longer than PojectA and the url is shown in full

Comment: Add screen shots for both scenarios.

Comment: you are 100% correct,, the other sites have shorter url .. but still in my case the whole url is shown "_pmo/programmes/pojecta_" but with additional "_..._" so the result was confusing ""_pmo/programmes.../pojecta_""... this is strange ,, while in ur example the "_SubProjectSubProjectSubProject_" was truncated but in my case no truncation happen

Comment: Could you count character before "..." dots. Any way your site is not corrupted that i can tell you. It's only the display, when space is short Microsoft truncate some characters.

Comment: before the "..." i have 50 charecters

Comment: So when ever url reaches 50 characters , Microsoft put "..." no matter if it's last character.

Comment: thanks for your help.. looks like the situation is clear to me now..